# Is there a simple way to copy "LaTeX code" from IPython LaTeX-png in Spyder?

Tags: python, latex, ipython, png, spyder

I have set up IPython console in Spyder to output in LaTeX with sympy via

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing(use_latex=True)
```

The output now is a LaTeX style png. Now I would like to copy paste the underlying "LaTeX code" into my .tex file. How can I do that efficiently, how do I get the LaTeX from this png output?

E.g. from the output of

```
a, b, c, d  = sy.symbols('a b c d')
sy.Eq(a**2*(b-c),d)
```

which is a^2(b-c)=d, but in a fancy LaTeX-png, I would like to get something like

```
a^{2} \left(b-c\right) = d
```

In reality the equations are much more complex and there are a lot of them and I don't want to transcribe them all manually.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself

```
sy.print_latex(sy.Eq(a**2*(b-c),d))
```

does the trick!

printing this in the console gives the output

```
a^{2} \left(b - c\right) = d
```

like I wanted.